# How to create a route map for a campus?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, google-maps

I need to create a route map for a campus and i should up able to search the route by entering the from and to location.

I need to show in a web page.

What are possible ways to do it?

I know HTML,javascript,Jquery,Asp.net,c#

Is there any available plug-ins or is there any logic?

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far?  Google Maps has a pretty well documented route finder API - http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/

Especially for a campus, they have the ability to change the route via the mode of transportation.